# Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll for Silverlight application

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to add reference to a non-Silverlight assembly to a Silverlight application?

I want to add a reference to `Microsoft.sqlserver.smo.dll` to my Silverlight application.

urgent please

Comment: No - Silverlight runs on the client side, possibly in your browser - and it does not have any direct connection to the server-side SQL Server machine (and it should not have such a connection!)

Comment: You should put your SMO functionality into a WCF service on your backend (which will have a reference to the SMO DLLs), and then just call that WCF service from your Silverlight app.